# Automation engine is unable to playback the test because it is not able to interact with the desktop

Tags: tfs, coded-ui-tests, autologin

I am trying to run Coded UI tests and I get this message. This happens only if I disconnect from the remote session or I have it minimized.
I enabled autologon, the agent is running in interactive mode, disabled screen saver and lock screen but still not working.
What should I try next?

Comment: Typing you question into a web search gives back lots of useful results. What happened when you tried those resources before asking the question here?

Comment: Much better solution can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/355935/how-can-i-restore-a-remote-desktop-session-to-the-local-console#comment1377484_914634).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to not connect visa remote desktop. Connect once and reboot the machine and do not connect.

Every time you RDP to the test box you need to reset it by rebooting.

Reason: The reason for this is that starting a remote desktop session suspends the local desktop session that the agent needs in order to run tests

Comment: The reason for this is that starting a remote desktop session suspends the local desktop session that the agent needs in order to run tests.

Comment: Best answer and best explanation in the comment!!